# Winforms: How to create a listbox with variable item height

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I need a simple listbox control where height for each item varies. And then i to need draw a custom image for each item.

Basically item_height would be equal to (listbox_width / image_width ) * image_height.

Normally I would just take a listbox and specify on paint event, but i need a variable height for each item.

Is there a simple way to get a list box with items of variable height?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the [DrawMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode.aspx) property of your `ListBox` control to [OwnerDrawVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drawmode.aspx) and handle its [MeasureItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.measureitem.aspx) and [DrawItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx) events.

Comment: can you please provide a code sample for the same /

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`MeasureItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.measureitem.aspx) event. Don't forget to set [`DrawMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode.aspx) to `OwnerDrawVariable`.